# SQL Select where not working

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I am using Python/Flask and trying to query my DB.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('./flaskdb.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=\'%s\'', "name")
```

I have 2 columns, `email, password` and the value `name, password` as one of the row/entries.

Why isn't this working? I get the error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 7 supplied.
```

Comment: Please post a complete example so that we can see the at least the entire python statement that is causing the error.  As always, a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please show the full code.  Typically with prepared statements you don't need to worry about using single quotes around parameters because the API takes care of that for you.

Comment: @2ps, updated the code

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Updated the code

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting bogged down with using prepared statements here.  Try this code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('./flaskdb.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
name = 'someone@somewhere.com'
cur.execute('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=?', (name,))
```

Corrections include using `?` as a placeholder instead of `%s`, the latter which is what might be used for other databases.  Also, if you want to bind a variable called `name`, then it too should not have quotes around it.

Comment: Thanks! That %s is not allowed though, it is expecting an expression

Comment: Sorry, I meant syntax error and sqlite3.Operationerror

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution:

```
cur.execute('SELECT password FROM users WHERE email=(?)', (email,))
```

you need it as a tuple and `(?)` as a placeholder.